# php Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in functions.php

Tags: php

getting this php fatal error on this line when try apply theme

```
case('homeimage_texts'):

                if(!empty(Params::getParam('homeimage'))){
                    foreach(Params::getParam('homeimage',false,false,false) as $key => $value){
                        osc_set_preference($key,trim($value),'osclasswizards_theme');
                    }
                }
                osc_add_flash_ok_message(__('Banner settings updated correctly', OSCLASSWIZARDS_THEME_FOLDER), 'admin');

                osc_redirect_to(osc_admin_render_theme_url('oc-content/themes/'.OSCLASSWIZARDS_THEME_FOLDER.'/admin/settings.php#banner'));
            break;
```

Comment: `empty()` takes a variable until __php5.5__. `Params::getParam('homeimage')` is not a variable.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a PHP version issue. I you are using PHP 5.3 or below you may get this error message.

Comment: And what is the solution?